# Why does C# allow heterogeneous IList

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Why is following code compiling fine in C# 4.0? I was expecting such potential code will be caught by the compiler; but to my surprise, this code compiles fine. Can anyone explain to what extend does the C# compiler goes to ensure type safety?

```
    IList<IAnimal> al = new List<IAnimal>();
    al.Add(new Dog()); //Dog implements IAnimal
    al.Add(new Cat()); //Cat implements IAnimal
    foreach (var animal in al)
    {
        ((Dog)animal).Bark(); //Application crash when current item is Cat
    }
```

Comment: It won't be caught by the compiler, but some static language analyzers like Resharper may very well be able to detect this.

Comment: Note that Linq provides `OfType<T>` and `Cast<T>` to handle this sort of functionality more cleanly.  The former skips non-matching elements  and the latter throws an exception on non-matching elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone explain to what extend does the C# compiler goes to ensure
>   type safety?

Generally, the compiler ensures type safety by knowing the type (or types) of every expression and making sure that no expression is used in a context that doesn't make sense. For example, an object can be assigned to a variable of its declared type (in that context), or any of the types it inherits from, or any of the types they inherit from.

In your example, you have the variable `al`, which is of type `IList<IAnimal>`. This creates a concrete type from the generic `IList<T>`, which exposes a method `Add(T)`, where `T` is now `IAnimal`. Therefore, `al` is declared to have a method `Add(IAnimal)`.

The expression `new Cat()` is of type `Cat`. If the type `Cat` is a class that extends from `object` and implements `IAnimal`, then it can be used in place of any expression that's expected to be `Cat`, `IAnimal` or `object`.

The above means that the expression `new Cat()` is a valid argument for the method `Add(IAnimal)`.

The cast, later on, attempts to cast or convert the object to the specified type. If at runtime the actual object isn't convertible, it throws an exception. The cast expression explicitly doesn't check type safety at compile time.

> Why is following code compiling fine in C# 4.0?

C# verifies the validity of each expression and each statement for type safety and, if the source satisfies the requirements set by the specification, the program is valid. Your program technically satisfies the spec.

You are right that a static analyzer could catch the suspicious cast here. But the compiler isn't necessarily a *thorough* static analyzer and, more importantly, the kind of problem you're describing is very narrow: In this particular case, the error will definitely be caught at debugging (since there is no way to avoid it), so it's not that big a deal. In any other case, the compiler wouldn't be able to detect it as suspicious code.

So, put simply, the C# compiler team probably realized that this is a kind of error that can be caught statically only in the most trivial cases. So, they didn't implement any checks about this scenario, since they'd rarely be useful (meaning: seen by anyone) in practice in any non-trivial program.

Answer (score 12):

The cast operator explicitly tells the compiler to ignore type safety and pretend that you know what you're doing.
It's meant to be used in situations where you *know* the actual type of an object, even though the compiler can't prove it.

Because C# is a *memory-safe* language, messing up will throw an `InvalidCastException`  (as opposed to C++, where it will invoke undefined behavior and silently corrupt things).

Comment: Note that `foreach(Dog animal in al)` would do the exact same thing, just hiding the cast.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: For more information, see http://blog.slaks.net/2011/09/c-is-not-type-safe.html

Comment: foreach was to demo how dangerous the code is. I was wondering why the list.Add() is allowing both Cat and Dog to it.

Comment: @Dan Why wouldn't it? You specifically told the compiler that you want it to accept anything implementing `IAnimal`, which `Dog` and `Cat` do.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the SLaks answer, the compiler can detect the problem when the list is of a type that definitely cannot be cast to Dog, i.e.:

```
IList<Cat> al = new List<Cat>();
al.Add(new Cat());
foreach (var animal in al)
{
    ((Dog)animal).Bark();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This behavior is allowed because of polymorphism. Let's say the `IAnimal` interface declares a method called `Communicate()` for example. When a dog implements it, it will bark. When it's a cat, it will miaow.

This allows to do this quite easily :

```
foreach(IAnimal animal in al)
{
    al.Communicate();
}
```

This is why this is allowed.

Comment: did you understand the question ?

Comment: Have you read the question's title ? Also, seeing the comments Dan makes in the answer below, I guess he wanted to know why we would use an `IList<IAnimal>`.